# NAN loss while training a image segmentation model with non-object images

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I am currently working on a multi-class image segmentation application. A fraction of dataset contains images whose corresponding ground-truth images do not contain any object (completely black background). I am using Dice loss and when I trained the model with this dataset, it diverged to NAN after some epochs. Despite of using a small epsilon/smoothness factor that controls the underflow/overflow while calculating DICE loss, it still diverged to zero. I checked my dataset and tried a few things to overcome this issue (including clipping the gradient norm) but the issue didnt resolve. (For reference, I opened this issue on stack-overflow but could not get any answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259112/dice-loss-becomes-nan-after-some-epochs?noredirect=1#comment110115202_62259112). However, when I removed those images whose ground-truth does not contain any object, the training became stabilized and NAN issue did not appear. I do not understand why the ground-truth images with no objects should be causing this issue? Any insights?